# Is ReceiveTimeout applied to stashed messages

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

Let's say I have abstract actor with 2 states

`Ready` and `Busy`.

In Busy state I want to receive only particular type of messages e.g `PauseJob`, `CancelJob`, all other messages like `StartNewJob` get stashed.

**Question:** if I set `SetReceiveTimeout()` in Busy state, is it applied only to messages that I actually process in this state (`PauseJob`, `CancelJob`) or stashed messages are also considered?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, stashed messages are also considered because the actor is still active while it's stashing the messages.

When you use `SetRecieveTimeout()` the `RecieveTimeout` message is sent when the actor hasn't received any messages for the designated amount of time.

```
private void Busy()
{
    SetReceiveTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    Receive<PauseJob>(msg =>
    {
        // Do something
    });

    Receive<ReceiveTimeout>(timeout =>
    {
        // I won't run until 1 second after 
        // all messages are processed or stashed
    });

    ReceiveAny(msg =>
    {
        Stash.Stash();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it's impossible to set receive timeout only for particular message types, will have to implement it manually